# Function-like CSS Classes

Tags: css

EDIT:  I apologize if this has been asked before or is a well-known techinque.  I didn't know what this would be called and hence I was unable to search for it.

In my HTML document, I vertically center something as follows:

```
<div style='position:  absolute; margin:  auto; top:  0; bottom:  0; height:  500px'>
<!-- CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

This works great, the only problem is, the code isn't quite reusable because it depends on the particular height of the block.  What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<div class='vcenter(500px)'>
<!-- CONTENT HERE -->
</div>

.vcenter(height)
{
    position:  absolute;
    margin:  auto;
    top:  0;
    bottom:  0;
    height:  height;
}
```

If I could implement something like this, then I would not have to duplicate code every time I wanted to vertically center something.  Does CSS have a way of implementing this?

Comment: Unfortunately CSS doesn't have stuff like this... This is my wish also :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a css expression, but dont. It's badly supported by browsers and bad practice.

I would recommend using a css generating tool: 
http://lesscss.org/ or http://compass-style.org/

Answer (score 4):

You're not happy with doing it this way?

```
<div class='vcenter' style='height: 500px'>
<!-- CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

Comment: That would definitely work in this case.  I guess the vertical-alignment was a bad example.  I wasn't so much interested in the vertical-alignment per se so much as knowing if CSS had such a feature, because my (possibly naive) guess is that it would come in very handy other places.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of doing this with native CSS. I suggest looking at a Javascript solution.

A jQuery solution would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var newHeight = $(window).height() * someRatio;
        $("#yourElement").css('height', newHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens if the user never resizes the window? I don't think that the OP needs it to happen when the window is resized.

Comment: Pretty sure `resize()` is called when the window is first instantiated. If I'm wrong, just put the same code in the `onReady` handler.

Answer (score -1):

Use two classes.

```
<div class="universal specific-style">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Where `.universal` and `specific-style` should have more semantic names. Then, in your stylesheet:

```
.universal {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.specific-style {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: downvoter: what exactly is wrong with this? CSS doesn't have a native approach to this, and my answer is a semantic, meaningful approach.